# Visual Studio debugger - Displaying integer values in Hex

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, integer, hex

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and I have just noticed that the debugger is displaying integer values as Hex when I hover over variables and also in the immediate window.  I guess I must have hit a shortcut key accidently or something.

Anyone had this before?  How do I set it back to display in decimal?

Comment: Believe it or not, this was also upsetting the increment of declared integers with big oopses like `f + 1 = 10 (dec)`.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

Right-click your [Watch Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290869%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and uncheck Hexadecimal Display option.

[image]

Comment: wasn't available in Tools Dialog.  Only way I could change it back was to add Variable to Watch window and right click in Value field and then I had the Hexadecimal Display check box.

Comment: I was able to do it in the **Call Stack** window in VS2010.

Comment: Was in the Debugging toolbar for me.

Comment: I think its in the watch window not immediate window.

Comment: @Soham Dasgupta: if you read the question you see that the user is using Visual Studio 2008 and he mentions the Immediate Window. The answer I provided here is useful in his case as it solves the problem for that specific version of VS. The comments above shows different ways of achieving the same result in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Thanks God i got rid of this stupid annoying thing. Thanks @Leniel

Comment: I'm using VS2013 and can't find where that option is. and sometimes it's hard to follow stackoverflow comments because my tool menus are all Korean..

Comment: Still relevant in 2020 with VS 2019!

Comment: Note that there is no indication that it also changes the value of the variable hovers in your code view once you exit the watch window.  But this is what you wanted I hope.

Answer (score 51):

You can also choose **hexadecimal** or **decimal** display on a per-variable basis in the **Visual Studio watch window** by appending a debugger format specifier to the variable name. In the watch window, enter:

```
myInt,h
myInt,d
```

The other very useful format specifiers are `ac` (see footnote) for 'always calculate', and `nq` for displaying with 'no quotes.' They can be used together:

```
my_string_func(),ac,nq
```

`nq` is useful inside `DebuggerDisplay` attributes, which can appear on a class:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{my_string_func(),nq}")]
class MyClass
{
    /* ...example continues below... */
```

...or on one or more field(s) inside a class:

```
    [DebuggerDisplay("{some_field,nq}", Name="substitute name here")]
    int an_integer;

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    String some_field;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby(v=VS.100).aspx

- note that earlier versions of the MSDN doc page incorrectly said 'Ac' (with a capital 'A')--which doesn't work

Comment: +1, but although MSDN states that `h` is the correct modifier for hex display, it seems (at least in my version, VS 2012 Premium) that `x` works instead (e.g. `1024,x` instead of `1024,h`). Placing `h` returns the "CXX0026 bad format string" error.

Comment: I suspect that might depend on the language that the module that's being debugged was written in. It's certainly true that debugger expression syntax changes according to the current language. From your message, it appears that you were using C++; I answered as if for C#, although perhaps I shouldn't have assumed that since the OP didn't specify.

Comment: This provides better discretional control on formatting vs the all or nothing of "Hexadecimal Display"

Answer (score 23):

There is a Hex button shown when Visual Studio is run in Debug mode to enable/disable the Hex display

[image: Visual Studio Debug Mode - hex button]

Comment: This is an overlooked button same as Hexadecimal Display in context menu, thanks.

Answer (score 14):

**Right-click on client space of almost every debug window** (except Immediate Window) - watch/locals/autos/threads/call stack - and **uncheck "Hexadecimal Display"** option.
There's also a **"Hex" button in debug toolbar**  (right to "Step Over" by default) when debugging.

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio 2010 I also saw it in the Debug toolbar, it was highlighted in yellow 'Hex', I just clicked it and it returned to (normal) decimal values

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio 2017
Decimal vs. hexadecimal display is controlled only from the Watch dialog.

1. Break after setting the variable.
2. Right mouse click the variable and select "Add Watch" or "QuickWatch"
3. Right mouse click the line in the Watch dialogue.
4. Uncheck "Hexadecimal Display"

The display will now be in decimal.

[image]

Comment: vs2022 works same

Answer (score 3):

In the immediate window you can uncheck the  Hexadecimal Display option.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022 17.8.3

The only available selection for changing HEX display mode is in the Watch window.
Have to perform a breakpoint and then add a watch variable. Then the hexadecimal mode can be turned off.
There is no general selection for the output window for this.