# Linq returning wrong value from DB

Tags: asp.net, wcf-ria-services

I have a super simple select in a wcf service like

```
 BusinessModel.Candidate candidateObject
                = dcMUPView.Candidates.SingleOrDefault(dev => dev.Username == username);
```

But when I hit this code, and then check the candidateObject, it's candidateid value is incorrect. In the DB candidateid is the identity column and primary key. In this case it is 2572884 in the DB but when I look in the candidateObject is says the value returned is something like 0x00274254. Anyone know what might cause something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query is returning the correct record, since 0x00274254 (base 16) = 2572884 (base 10).

If you are checking the value using the debugger, make sure you have the Hexadecimal Display option turned off (see here for more info: [Visual Studio debugger - Displaying integer values in Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex)).