# C# display of intergers as binary/decimal. How do you change the display?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have the following simple variable, set to 1 in Visual Studio C#.  When I view intellisense of test it shows as 0x00000001.  Back a few years ago, from schoool, if I remember correctly this is the decimal/binary representaion of the number. I can't remember.  Anyway is there a setting to get it back to the normal view of when it is 1 it is displayed as 1.  Probably a stupid question!

```
int test = 1;
```

Comment: `0x` is for hexadecimal.

Comment: Since the VS versions are different, this might not apply, but [try this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you view the value during debugging, right-click on the number and uncheck Hexadecimal Display

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but please crop your image next time! :)

Comment: I did crop it, but forgot to save )))

Comment: Dang...that is all. I can't believe I didn't know that!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Watch Window, you will have the "HexaDecimal Display" ticked. Uncheck it.