# C# int.TryParse("3",out tst) AND Convert.ToInt32("3") returning 0x00000003 instead of 3 what can it be?

Tags: c#, asp.net

All my code works fine until i did some changes that i cant track right now.
 when i debugg my code i can see that the converting returning hex instead of number.
I have no idea why its happening or what can cause this.
any ideas please?
Thanks.

Comment: `0x3`, `03`, and 3 are all the same.

Comment: yes I know but i want the number and the reason why it Suddenly returning hex

Comment: What I'm saying is the Framework is not returning anything "in hex". An integer value is an integer value. When displayed as a string it may differ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio debugger - Displaying integer values in Hex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the value in a debugger. Integer values are not stored "in hex" or even "in decimal". 3 is stored in binary, but viewed based on your debugger settings.

You can disable hexadecimal viewing by right clicking in the [Watch or Immediate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex) view and deselecting Hexadecimal Display.

Answer (score 5):

It's a VS feature, You can disable it:

[image: desc]