# string Convert to int value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert the string value to int value, so I tried these things:

```
// 1.
string a = "4163";
int b = int.Parse(a);

// 2.
int intValue;
int.TryParse(a, out intValue);

// 3.
int b = Convert.ToInt32(a);
```

but always my output looks like this:

[image: Wrong output value in debugger]

It always writes `0x00001043`, but I need `4163` as output. What is the wrong with my code?

Comment: Show the code you used to output `b`; possibly you are using `{0:X}` ?

Comment: how do you print the output?

Comment: All of those work. How do you print your output? Btw, 0x00001043 is 4163 in hexadecimal.

Comment: Code looks good, has to do with your output I suppose. Please provide more code.

Comment: Side note: "output" is usually console output of a program (or some other form, like text file). What you show in the question is usually called with explicitly calling "debugger XXX" - "debugger view", "watch list"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You code should work as expected. May be you need to change the display settings. So do something like this

> Right click the Watch Window and deselect the Hexadecimal Display of
>   values.

Comment: +1, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex)

Comment: You are copy then past in this answer :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex

Comment: @RameshRams ohh really?

Comment: Yes .. You can see that !!!! this is not a answer. it's like a comment only . and this answer was possible duplicate

Comment: @RameshRams so what do you think what's the correct answer of the OP's problem?

Comment: The OP's have a answer ,for Why he see a watch window ???

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure it'll parse correctly, use

```
int.Parse(string)
```

If you're not, use

```
int i;
bool success = int.TryParse(string, out i);
```

Caution! In this case, i will equal 0, not 10 after the TryParse.

```
int i = 10;
bool failure = int.TryParse("asdf", out i);
```

This is because TryParse uses an out parameter, not a ref parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
 int i = Convert.ToInt16("1234");
```

and I think the way you are converting is also correct but you are having problem while u are displaying on the console.

try to display that converted integer in html or somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Hey Your all converting way's is give correct answer . You don't see a answer in a quick watch. You can check for final value on the `b` .

for sample

```
// 1.
string a = "4163";
int b = Convert.ToInt32(a);
```

the `b` is return correct answer , you want to check for add below line

```
int c =b;//now it's show result for  4163
```