# DataRow Column value returned as hexavalue instead of integer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Please view the image with the code and the integer value being loaded with hexa values.

[image: Code-Debugging Screenshot]

The data retreived from SQL and loaded to datatable, but the data retrieved in the first column of my database is an identity column of type int. But the value returned by the datarow column is showing a hexa value(0x00000001). Why is that so? But if i convert to string it is showing as "1". But if convert to string and then back to int then also the hexa value is showing up.

What needs to be done to fix this issue?

Comment: You have the debugger set to display integer values in hexadecimal.

Comment: How to modify the debugger to display properly?

Comment: Did you google? First result for `visual studio debugger displaying integer values in hex`: [Visual Studio debugger - Displaying integer values in Hex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex)

Answer (score -1):

[Visual Studio debugger - Displaying integer values in Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex) helped me fix the issue.

1. Clicked on Watch window at the bottom
2. right clicked inside the space within the box.
3. Hexadecimal display was ticked, removed it to fix the issue.

Thanks HABO!!!