# Return type is byte[] instead of INT in webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, integer, type-conversion, byte

I have an integer attribute in Active Directory Lightweight Directory services.

[image]

In my `webservices` I access that attribute and read it's value.

```
...
SearchResult results = searcher.FindOne();

if (results !=null)
{
   if (results.Properties["userStatus"] != null)
   {
      user.Status = (UserStatusEnum) results.Properties["userStatus"][0];
   } 
}
...
```

This line returns correct data:

```
results.Properties["userStatus"][0]
```

`Value = 1` *(returns integer)*

However, I'm running into an issue when I point my external webservices to internal services.

When I do that and I execute this line:

```
results.Properties["userStatus"][0]
```

for the same user, the same value it's now returning

> {byte[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5spR.png)}
>       [0]: 49

If I set the status to `2` it will return

> {byte[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5spR.png)}
>       [0]: 50

and so on...

Why is this happening? How can I resolve this issue, or at least debug?

I have tried to remove my `external` webservices out of the equation and pointed my `web application` directly to `internal` webservices. I get the same results.

### SOLVED

Thanks to *ps2goat* I wrote some code to accomplish what I need. I'm still interested on finding out ***"Why it's working fine using internal webservices, but not when we call it using external webservice?!***

```
object statusObj = results.Properties["userStatus"][0];
if (statusObj is byte[])
{
   string statusString System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString((byte[])statusObj);
   user.Status = (UserStatusEnum)Convert.ToInt32(statusString);
}
else
{ 
   user.Status = (UserStatusEnum)Convert.ToInt32(statusObj);
}
```

Comment: `49` is the ascii value for the integer `1`. It looks like you need to cast it back to a `char`.  http://www.klcconsulting.net/ascii.htm  look at decimal value 49.  So if the user value is `10`, maybe it will return `{49, 48}` for 1 and 0.

Comment: @ps2goat, If it's 1 it returns `49`, if it's 2 it returns `50`, if it's 3 it returns `51` and so on... I have tried converting it to `char` but I get `Invalid object cast`.

Comment: right, check what `10` returns.  If you convert the string value of `10` to bytes, it will be `{49,48}` in ascii.  That table I linked to has a list of decimal (byte) values to character values.  Once you get to double digits, you can see the real pattern.

Comment: @ps2goat, you are right. The value `10` returns `{byte[2]}[0]: 49 [1]:48` I do see the pattern. But unfortunately, I cannot convert the `byte` to `char`.

Comment: I'd say there's something wrong with the web service contract, then (WSDL).  Or is this a RESTful service, etc.?  Please give us more information.

Comment: If is another project, maybe your VS is set for show values in ex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex

Comment: @ps2goat,  I was able to resolve the issue using the hint you gave me about ASCII characters. If you put that as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`49` is the ASCII value for the integer 1. It looks like you need to cast the byte values back to `char`s, then to `int`s.

Here's an ASCII table to reference: klcconsulting.net/ascii.htm look at decimal value `49` to see that it is the decimal value for the ASCII character `1`. If the user value is `10`, it should return two bytes `{49, 48}`, the first for `1` and the second for `0`.

Answer (score -1):

So, I've had to deal with a similar problem to this before. As an int, those are the correct results, but the literal version of it is +48 (if you stay within 0-9) because that is where the numbers in the character code begins. If you subtract 48 you will get your answer within the first 10 digits, once you get over that it becomes a little more crazy to get the information.

Comment: I do see a pattern and I can come up with a solution, however, why is it happening? I should just get `1`.

Comment: It depends on how you are looking at the bits, if you are printing them as raw, it probably assumes its a string literal and converts it to char automatically.

Comment: I tried storing it into `char` and convert my results to `char`, no luck.