# For all indices in visual studio shows Hex value?

Tags: c#

In my c# code:

```
int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

Row count shows value of 0 which is not valid. When a breakpoint is placed it shows values as Count 0x00000001

Comment: All indices in project shows hex values instead of int

Comment: Interesting, hex is 1 in decimal. Can you post your codes?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex

Comment: sorry MonoLightTech we are not authorize to upload the code .....

Comment: code is same as in question

Comment: The row count is initially -1 when you call the constructor for the table.  After you add at least one column the count becomes zero.  After you add the first row then the row count is greater than zero.

Comment: If you just want the debugger to show values in decimal instead of hex, just right-click in the Locals window and toggle the "Hexadecimal display" option.

Comment: thank you all,  now it shows integer value ....when the option HexaDecimal Display is unchecked in Watch window