# Values displayed as Hexadecimal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

Instead of actual numbers, 0x000 are present in the result

Works fine in friend's system, but I get this result

[image: C# code Debug (Screen Shot)]

[image: Sql Server (Screen Shot)]

Comment: question is not clear enough to get an answer/support

Comment: please click the link, to see the screen shot, i dont rights yet to upload direct images

Comment: go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex it should help. You are seeing everythin in hex.

Comment: Are you speaking about `0x00...` values shown in the watch window? Right click inside the Locals window and uncheck "Hexadecimal Display".

Comment: yes, that was the problem, i unchecked it, thanks

Comment: Thanks Everyone, i dont have much reputation to show my gratitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f3kd7d.aspx) you are seeing the values in Hex.

Just right-click in the debugger console and uncheck hexadecimal display.

Or whenever you are debugging just click as shown on the image (extracted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17433749/1468942)):

[image]