# JSON deserialization error on integer types - C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I am implementing for the first time a POST in WebAPI from an Angular client that receives a JObject which I then deserialize to my objects of interest. 
But when I check the resulting object I see that all fields are appropriately filled except those meant to be integers.

This is part of my POST method

```
 // POST: api/PresupuestosApi
    [ResponseType(typeof(Presupuesto))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPresupuesto([FromBody]JObject presupuesto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        try
        {
            Presupuesto p = presupuesto.ToObject<Presupuesto>();
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{  
"sTitulo": "Agentasa",  
"cSolicitante": 
{
    "eRol": "SOLICITANTE",
    "sEmail": "bla@sdlfkjsf.com",
    "iTelefono": "122299935",
    "sNombre": "Clau",
    "sApellido": "Clau"  
},  
"cTrabajo": 
{
    "SNombreTrabajo": "Agenda"  

},  
"sMaterial": "sadsa",  
"sDimAbierto": "12x22",  
"sDimCerrado": "12x155",  
"sImpresion": "Una cara",  
"fGramaje": 12.5,  
"iCantidad": 122,  
 }
```

And my `Presupuesto` class is this:

```
public class Presupuesto
{
    private int iIdPresupuesto;
    private string sTitulo;
    private Solicitante cSolicitante;
    private Trabajo cTrabajo;
    private string sMaterial;
    private string sDimAbierto;
    private string sDimCerrado;
    private float fGramaje;
    private string sImpresion;
    private int iCantidad;
  }
```

So, when debugging I see this:

[image: p object]

I am lost as to why it is correctly parsing every other type but int.
Any suggestions on this subject? I need to emphasize I have never worked with WebAPI before.

Comment: There is only one int in your screenshot and it seems to have the same value as it has in the JSON. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: are you setting any content type header on the client side, specifically on the http.post method of ur angular app? And why dont u directly bind the posted values into a Presupuesto object?

Comment: @moreON The only int here is iCantidad, and it is being set to 0x0000007a (what is this? A memory location?). Shouldn't it be 122, like the int i submitted in the JSON?

Comment: `0x0000007a` in Hex = `122` in Dec

Comment: @AllenKing so why is it being saved as Hex?

Comment: @emmaielle  check your debugger settings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex

Comment: @AllenKing perfect! I'm glad I know that now

Comment: @emmaielle I am glad. Let me answer the question formally then :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x0000007a` in Hex = `122` in Dec.  Check your debugger settings. Debugger seems to be set to display integers in Hex.