# Debugger is showing integer values as hexadecimal

Tags: c#, asp.net

Textbox text is number, and after `int.Parse` the debugger is showing the value as HEX rather than the value of 958 that I expect.

[image]

Comment: Is intellisense showing you a **different representation** of the value ? https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter

Comment: The VS debugger represents numeric values in hexadecimal format, hence the hex number is exactly same as stored in the variable.

Comment: There is a Hex button shown when Visual Studio is run in Debug mode to enable/disable the Hex display. Try that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio debugger - Displaying integer values in Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex)

Comment: Yeah enable Disable that hexa decimal view - then its working fine.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it is parsing correctly.

Your debugger is just showing you the value in hexadecimal.

948 in base 10 is equal to 3b4 in hexadecimal.

Comment: Yeah enable Disable that hexa decimal view - then its working fine.Thanks  a lot

Answer (score 0):

While debugging open Locals Window, right click value displaying in Hex and click Hexdecimal Display.

Done, displays in Decimal.