# DotNet Core's GraphQL casting parameter value to integer

Tags: c#, graphql, graphiql, graphql-dotnet

I'm using graphql-dotnet ([dotnet GraphQl](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/)) for implementing GraphQL in DotNet Core 2.1.  I have the following classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerInputType : InputObjectGraphType
{
    public CustomerInputType()
    {
        Name = "CustomerInput";
        Field<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>>(nameof(Customer.Id));
        Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>(nameof(Customer.Name));
    }
}
public class CustomerOutputType : ObjectGraphType<Customer>
{
    public CustomerOutputType()
    {
        Name = "Customer";
        Field<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>>(nameof(Customer.Id));
        Field<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>(nameof(Customer.Name));
    }
}
public class CustomerMutation : ICustomerMutation
{
    public void Resolve(GraphQLMutation graphQLMutation)
    {
        graphQLMutation.FieldAsync<CustomerOutputType, Customer>
        (
            "createCustomer",
            arguments: new QueryArguments
            (
                new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<CustomerInputType>> { Name = "customer"}
            ),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                var customer = context.GetArgument<Customer>("customer");
                return Task.FromResult(customer);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Here's the input I'm sending to this mutation via GraphIQL:

```
mutation createCustomer
{ 
    createCustomer(customer:{id: 19, name: "Me"})
    {id name} 
}
```

Here's the input inside C# Code:

[image]

The watch is showing the value of id to be `0x00000013` instead of `19`.

Here's the output in GraphIQL:

[image]

I need to use the value of `19` for further processing in a repository which is injected into this mutation.  However, when I pass the Customer object to the repository, the value of id in Customer object is `0x00000013` which causes further downstream processing to fail because it's expecting `19` instead of `0x00000013`.

Why is the value of the object `0x00000013` inside C# code yet gets translated to the actual value in GraphIQL?  How do I cast the value of Cusutomer.id to its correct integer value for further processing before the mutation returns results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct, the value is just being displayed as Hex. It's your inspector that's confusing you. 13 hex as binary is

```
10011
```

And that is decimal

```
19
```

https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html

Comment: yes, it is displayed as Hex.  Why is it doing that in Visual Studio

Comment: Try right clicking the panel while debugging and see if you can change the setting
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex

Comment: Yes, I'm an idiot.  For whatever reason hexadecimal display was turned on.  Thank you.  Looking at code tooo long...

Comment: It happens to all of us! =D