# Assembly Addition summation under 15 auto converts to hex

Tags: assembly, hex, irvine32

for my assignment I have to make a fibonacci sequence that generates up to 15 numbers. Whenever I add any numbers that sum between 10-15, I get the hex value of them in memory and in the register. What do I do about that?

Im using eax and ebx to add the numbers and I cant figure out how to keep it from converting to hex. Every other number stays in decimal. For example when I add 8 and 5 using this code:

```
mov eax, 5
mov ebx, 8
add eax, ebx
```

The value in eax would be 0D, help?

Comment: Probably you get _always_ a hex view on your register, but don't recognize it? Without any sourcecode it's really hard to tell, what's going on. How do you view the values in the registers, by IDE or by outputting them? More informations are needed.

Comment: I use visual studio, when I debug i step through it and watch the registers in the ide, it also appears that way in memory. It adds decimal numbers normally until the result is in the range of 10-15

Comment: but values from 0 to 9 in decimal and hexadecimal just look the same, so that's not a "proof" that the register isn't just always displayed in hex

Comment: You are correct, how do I get it in decimal? In memory when I add 8 and 5 it is displayed as 0D, but then I add 0D and 8 and it gives 15?

Comment: Integers in registers are in binary.  It's up to your debugger to show them to you in some human-readable form, often hex or decimal depending on what options you choose or debugger commands you run.  Or if you're writing other code to display registers, e.g. `call DumpRegs`, it's up to that function how it formats registers.  You haven't said what you're using.  The bit-pattern in the register is the same regardless of how you interpret it as representing a value (normally unsigned or 2's complement signed) and display that value in some base, generating some bytes of text at some point.

Comment: I would say if you work in assembler get used to read hex numbers (but that's only because I don't know how to switch the view in Visual Studio ;-)  ... usually it's some right-click context menu entry or in the view menu. You could use windows calculator in programming mode or just multiply the first digit with 16 and add it to the second digit - 0xA = 10 decimal, 0xB = 11 decimal, ... 0xF = 15 decimal.

Comment: probably you will get help in answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354453/visual-studio-debugger-displaying-integer-values-in-hex